# CakePHP recursive delete

Tags: php, mysql, database, cakephp, model

There are posts and comments table.

For one post there are multiple comments.

If i delete one post will the comments for that post be automatically deleted in cakephp ?

Comment: http://book.cakephp.org/view/1039/Associations-Linking-Models-Together (look for "dependent")

Comment: do you want them to be deleted?

Comment: Yes, i want to delete those comments with that post. How can i do that ?

Comment: Have you tried it? http://book.cakephp.org/view/1036/delete: *"Deletes the record identified by $id. By default, also deletes records dependent on the record specified to be deleted."*

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> ```
> var $hasMany = array(
>   'Comment' => array(
>      'className' => 'Comment',
>      'foreignKey' => 'post_id',
>      'dependent'=> true
>    )
> );
> ```

Comment: 'dependent'=> true is the key !

Answer (score 1):

This really shouldn't be up to CakePHP... let your database handle that by using FOREIGN KEY constraints and set it to ON DELETE CASCADE

Answer (score 0):

If you are using the `foreign key Constraint` `ON DELETE CASCADE`, yes.

[See here](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/innodb-foreign-key-constraints.html) for documentation (works with engine InnoDB)

Comment: I didn't use foreign key constraint. var $hasMany=array('Comment'); and var $belongsTo = array('Post');