# How deep is the cakephp delete cascade

Tags: cakephp

I have three tables  Book->pages->assets when I delete a book I delete the pages associated with it. I also want to delete the assets associated with page when I delete a book.

How deep does book delete cascade go? My book and pages delete but not assets. If I know cakephp should delete the assets also then I know it is just my setup.

Book Model

```
public $hasMany = array(
    'Page' => array(
        'className' => 'Page',
        'foreignKey' => 'book_id',
        'dependent' => true,
        'conditions' => '',
        'fields' => '',
        'order' => 'order',
        'limit' => '',
        'offset' => '',
        'exclusive' => '',
        'finderQuery' => '',
        'counterQuery' => ''
    )
);
```

Page model

```
public $hasMany = array(
    'Asset' => array(
        'className' => 'Asset',
        'foreignKey' => 'page_id',
        'dependent' => true,
        'conditions' => '',
        'fields' => '',
        'order' => '',
        'limit' => '',
        'offset' => '',
        'exclusive' => '',
        'finderQuery' => '',
        'counterQuery' => ''
    )
);
```

}

Book Controller

```
$this->Book->delete($id, true)
```

Comment: tried http://stackoverflow.com/a/7267923/1501051  ?

Comment: you suggest letting the database look after the cascade delete? Asset is not directly related to the book being deleted

Comment: Is your asset association set as `dependent` too?